# How to use database name in a procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure which will output the `INSERT` script for a given table name. And in the procedure I am using this code:

```
DECLARE @owner VARCHAR(20) ,
    @Database VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @owner = 'dbo' ,
        @Database = 'Asmin'

 SELECT   sc.name
   FROM     sysobjects so
            INNER JOIN syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
            INNER JOIN systypes st ON sc.xtype = st.xusertype
   WHERE    so.Name = 'Acisd'
```

But the problem I see is the procedure is in collection database and the table `Acisd` is in different database. So it's returning me nothing when I execute procedure.

How to fix this?

Comment: Qualify table/proc/etc names with the database and schema, separated with periods. `db_name..object_name`, or `db_name.schema_name.object_name` (example: `db_name.dbo.object_name`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this inside a stored procedure you need to use dynamic SQL. For example:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = N'SELECT   sc.name
      FROM ' + quotename(@dbanme) + N'.sys.objects so
      INNER JOIN ' + quotename(@dbname) + N'sys.columns sc ON so.id = sc.id
      INNER JOIN ' + quotename(@dbname) + N'sys.types st ON sc.xtype = st.xusertype
      WHERE so.Name = @objectName';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@objectName sysname', @objectName;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error Msg 214, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_executesql, Line 1
Procedure expects parameter '@parameters' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you're going for here, but you could point this whole statement to the other database by fully qualifying the table references.

```
SELECT   sc.name
   FROM     OtherDatabase.dbo.sysobjects so
            INNER JOIN OtherDatabase.dbo.syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
            INNER JOIN OtherDatabase.dbo.systypes st ON sc.xtype = st.xusertype
   WHERE    so.Name = 'Acisd'
```

Comment: and if you're on SQL Server 2005 or newer, you should use `sys.columns` instead of `syscolumns` (and so on, for the other system catalog views, too)

Comment: @Joe Stefanelli Please see my updated question. I am using two variables for Schema name and Database so How do i use them?

Answer (score 0):

In sybase there is function db_name() to ktakeout current database ... not sure about sqlserver

Answer (score -1):

In MySQL there is a "Use" clause, which can precede any select statement.  I believe this is also the case in SQL - Server.

Comment: I know but you cannot use the 'Use' Clause inside the procedure

Answer (score -1):

As previus said the most easy way to do it is to simply start by

USE [otherDatabasename]

GO

DECLARE @owner VARCHAR(20) ,
    @Database VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @owner = 'dbo' ,
        @Database = 'Asmin'

SELECT   sc.name
   FROM     sysobjects so
            INNER JOIN syscolumns sc ON so.id = sc.id
            INNER JOIN systypes st ON sc.xtype = st.xusertype
   WHERE    so.Name = 'Acisd'

Comment: you cannot use the 'Use' Clause inside the procedure